# Can I host a website on a cloud service?

Tags: cpanel, host

I am thinking about paying for a domain name, and I wonder if I can host the files on Dropbox/Google Drive/any other free cloud service...

my question can be divided into two:

1) How can I link my domain name to the "public" html file hosted on my dropbox, if it's possible,

2) Could I have a cPanel, php, MySQL support through a free cloud service ? if not, how would I be able to, let's say, have a subdomain, email, or database ?

(Note, if it's possible to host static pages this way (since it's free) it would be a good option for an indie dev website for example, hence my question)
(P.s. I know that there are other free hosting companies (with fairly good bandwidth and storage) that do work well, but for concerns about disponibility and liability, using Dropbox or Google drive would be better)

Comment: It's partially possible ! (That's just a static HTML page can be rendered, However cPanel needs an Linux environment with root SSH access to be installed , PHP and MYSQL stack can't be installed there as far as i know :P)  Its definitely  not recommended proceeding working around this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, you can,here’s what you have to do:

1. Create a new folder in Drive and share it as “Public on the web.”
2. Upload your HTML, JS & CSS files to this folder.
3. Open the HTML file & you will see “Preview” button in the toolbar.
4. Share the URL that looks like www.googledrive.com/host/… from the preview window and anyone can view your web page.

2) Google drive will only allow you to use HTML, CSS and javascript. Likewise, you will not be able to use PHP and will have NO cpanel and MySql support.

P.S. Isn't it better for you to register a free hosting plan, e.g. `www.co.nf` and enjoy using subdomains and 300MB of hosting +MySql Database with latest version of PHP support and control panel? If you have purchased domain name you can configure its NAMESERVER settings and still use free hosting.

Comment: Yes you are right. Since cloud services won't support all the functionality of a (really small in size) website, it's better to go with a free hosting plan. Though, just by curiosity, could you explain how to "link" the purchased domain name with the URL of a publicly shared html file ? (in the first question)

Comment: I cannot tell you that since I am not sure whether it is possible to link a domain to a cloud storage. However, you can link purchased domain to a free hosting, or if you still want your files to be on drive, just create an empty HTML file on free hosting and write `window.location.href = 'your_google_drive_url'`, which will redirect you to the drive.